# Hive connector for scala?

Tags: scala, hive

Is there a connector between Apache Hive and Scala so I could write code in Scala that could execute hive commands? I was thinking of Shark and Spark, but they don't seem like they would do the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to call Java libraries from Scala code; you should be able to just use the Hive Java API.

Comment: do you mean this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface

Comment: You can use the JDBC interface, but you can also use the java/thrift client. [Here's the javadoc.](http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/api/) I'm having trouble finding good documentation, but you can try googling around.

Comment: Thanks Joe! Really appreciate it :)