# Integrate Play framrework with Berkeley Shark

Tags: playframework-2.0, shark-sql

I am trying to connect from a Plat 2.0.8 based Scala application to a Berkeley Shark context to fetch data from Shark tables. Can you please tell me how to do this. The Spark documentation is sparse.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run SQL queries using Shark, Shark's [sharkserver](https://github.com/amplab/shark/wiki/Shark-User-Guide#sharkserver) behaves like a regular Hive Thrift server, so you should be able to re-use existing Scala methods for connecting to Hive:

- [Hive connector for scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687729/hive-connector-for-scala)

Shark Server also supports Hive's [JDBC interface](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface), so you can use that to run queries from Scala; just use the Shark Server's address in place of the Hive Server address.

Answer (score 0):

Shark 0.91 contains  sharkserver2, and it equals hiveserver2 with hive version hive 0.11. So it could be connected by jdbc UI tools like "squirrel sql client" or others mentioned in hive page https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveJDBCInterface.
Also it could work with cloudera HUE 2.5, but it could not work with HUE 3.5.